# Ionic 4 ionViewDidEnter() didnt triggered after navigated from ion-back-button

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm having stuck with Ionic apps. My problem is I want to `refresh` the `root page` after `navigated from` the other page by clicking the `ion-back-button`, I'm trying to use the ionic lifecycle events.

Anyone having issues with the `ionViewDidEnter()` too (like in my case)? As I know these lifecycle event function, it’s fired when entering a page, before it becomes the active one.

This is DOM elements when the QR page become active:

[image]

As you can see there are 2 pages inside `<ion-router-outlet>`. In my situation, the `<app-home-tabs>` is the root page. To navigate to the `<app-my-qr>` page from the root page, I use `this.router.navigateByUrl('/my-qr'`, and then after I click `<ion-back-button>`, it's removed from the DOM.

[image]

The problem is the root page is not refreshed. I cant find the root caused of this problem..

home-tabs.router.module.ts:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a couple of days, I found the root caused and the solution.
Actually the problem is the child component won't refresh/reload... there is a child component `<app-home>` from `(home.page.ts)` inside the `<app-home-tabs>` which is can be seen inside the DOM elements.

The `ionViewWillEnter()` is not triggered in the child components `(home.page.ts)`.

home-tabs.router.module.ts:

[image]

After just put this function inside the parent component, which is the `home-tabs.page.ts`, `<app-home-tabs>`.
It calls the child component to force update itself. 
Just using the `import { Events } from '@ionic/angular';`

Parent component:

```
async ionViewDidEnter() {
    // This will be called everytime the page become active
    console.log('UpdateHome');
    this.events.publish('UpdateHome');
    ...
}
```

And inside the child component:

```
ionViewWillEnter() {
  this.events.subscribe('UpdateHome', async () => {
      console.log('UpdateHome');
      // Update itself
      let loading = await this.loadctrl.create();
      await loading.present();
      await this.getUser();
      this.menuCtrl.enable(true);
      await loading.dismiss();
  });
}
```

Answer (score 20):

I got the same issue, and just found a workaround from Ionic team member **liamdebeasi**:
https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/16834
He explains very well about this situation and provides a workaround. I just copy the code here, for more details please visit the link.

> Hi everyone,
>
> I wanted to provide an update regarding the status of this issue.
> After discussing with the team, we have determined this is not a bug
> in Ionic Framework; however, we realize there are valid use cases in
> which developers may want to listen for lifecycle events on an
> individual tab. Due to this, we have provided a temporary workaround
> as well as plans for further development.
>
> Why is this not a bug?
>
> When pages transition in Ionic Framework, they fire lifecycle events.
> For example, going from /page1 to /page2 would fire ionViewWillLeave
> and ionViewDidLeave events on the Page1 component and ionViewWillEnter
> and ionViewDidEnter events on the Page2 component. The same logic
> applies when going from /tabs/tab1 to /tabs/tab2. In both of these
> scenarios, we are staying within the same parent ion-router-outlet
> context.
>
> The reported issue occurs when navigating between ion-router-outlet
> contexts. In this case, we are seeing it when navigating from
> /tabs/tab1 to /page2. When this transition happens, Tab1 remains the
> active tab, and the entire tabs context transitions away. As a result,
> lifecycle events will fire on the root TabsPage component, but not on
> Tab1.
>
> For many users, this is unexpected because Tab1 visually appears to
> transition away. However, under the hood, the entire tabs context
> transitions away.
>
> What is the workaround?
>
> Luckily, there is an easy to use workaround for developers who wish to
> listen for lifecycle events on individual tab pages:

tabs.page.html

```html
<ion-tabs #tabs (ionTabsDidChange)="tabChange(tabs)">
  ...
</ion-tabs>
```

tabs.page.ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonTabs } from '@ionic/angular'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tabs',
  templateUrl: 'tabs.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tabs.page.scss']
})
export class TabsPage {
  private activeTab?: HTMLElement;

  constructor() {}
  
  tabChange(tabsRef: IonTabs) {
    this.activeTab = tabsRef.outlet.activatedView.element;
  }

  ionViewWillLeave() {
    this.propagateToActiveTab('ionViewWillLeave');
  }
  
  ionViewDidLeave() {
    this.propagateToActiveTab('ionViewDidLeave');
  }
  
  ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.propagateToActiveTab('ionViewWillEnter');
  }
  
  ionViewDidEnter() {
    this.propagateToActiveTab('ionViewDidEnter');
  }
  
  private propagateToActiveTab(eventName: string) {    
    if (this.activeTab) {
      this.activeTab.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(eventName));
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this .
Also happen to me recently .

```
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { IonBackButtonDelegate } from '@ionic/angular';

...
@ViewChild(IonBackButtonDelegate) backButton: IonBackButtonDelegate;
...

ionViewDidEnter() {
    console.log('ionViewDidEnter');
    this.setUIBackButtonAction();
  }

setUIBackButtonAction() {
this.backButton.onClick = () => {
  // handle custom action here
  console.log('is back on click');
  this.router.navigate(['/home-tabs/home'])
    .then(() => {
      window.location.reload();
    });
}
```

Comment: This work for me, but when the page is reloaded, the page become white screen instead of using router apps animation

Comment: Bad solution for a single page application

Answer (score 0):

I had same Problem. I used event of the NavigationEnd for the Navigation from non-tab-page to a tab-page with firing the Ionic Page Events. Code Snippet is below:

```
 constructor( private router: Router) {
 this.router.events
        .pipe(filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd))
        .subscribe((event: NavigationEnd) => {
            if (event.url === '/tabs/page-1') {
            console.log('page-1 has been entered.');
            //Here call the one event of Angular Life Cycle Events. In my case ngOnInit()
           this.ngOnInit();
         }
      });
  }
```

Answer (score -3):

You can Use

```
ionViewWillEnter()
{
  console.log("ionViewWillEnter entered");
}

ionViewDidEnter()
{
  console.log("ionViewDidEnter entered");
}
```